# Can a group have only one element from order $5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If I've got a group $G$. Is it possible for $G$ having only one element from order $5$?

---

I know that for example if we take $G$ as a cyclic group of order $n$, $G$ must have only one subgroup for each divisor of $n$. But what happens with the elements? Is it possible?

Comment: If an element $g$ has order $5$, what order does $g^2$ have? What about $g^{-1}$?

Comment: How can I know that?

Comment: If $g^5 = 1$ and $5$ is the order, you will arrive at contradictions after reducing the powers of $g^2$ into a single exponent. For example, $g^2 = 1$ can't happen as $5$ is the order of $g$. $(g^2)^2$ is similar. Continue in this manner.

Comment: The element of order $5$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $5$.

Comment: Thus we have at least $\phi(5)=4$ elements of order $5$ then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element of a group has order $5$, then so must its square, cube, and fourth power (which is also its inverse). Hence, a group with an element of order $5$ must have at least $4$ elements of order $5$.

Comment: But why? Because what I have mentioned?

Comment: What have you say is only with cyclic groups or with all groups?

Comment: @User160 Raising any element of finite order to a power coprime to the order does not change the order. Since $2$, $3$, and $4$ are all coprime to $5$, the square, cube, and fourth power of any element of order $5$ must also have order $5$ (in any group).

Answer (score 2):

If $g\in G$ has order $5$, then the subgroup $H=\langle g\rangle$ generated by $g$ is cyclic of order $5$. All non-trivial elements of $H$ (hence at least four elements of $G$) have order $5$.

Comment: Is that owing to the fact that in a cyclic group of order n, there are ϕ(n) elements of order $n$?

Comment: @User160 Yes, that is one way of seeing it. Another way is to realise that a group of prime order has no proper, non-trivial subgroups. So any non-trivial element generates the whole group.